# Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform problem

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, authentication

I want to do the sign-in method and I face this run time error ,I don't know the reason cause it or how to solve it.
I want to checks all cases for login

my code is:

```
 ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: logIn,
                    child: StreamBuilder<User?>(
                      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        // try{
                        print('inside bulder method');
                        if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                            ConnectionState.waiting) {
                          return const Center(
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                         
                        }
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          
                          print('have account');
                          return home();
                        } else {
                          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                              content: const Text('Invalid email/password'),
                              backgroundColor: Colors.red.shade400,
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(6, 0, 3, 0),
                              behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
                              action: SnackBarAction(
                                label: 'Dismiss',
                                disabledTextColor: Colors.white,
                                textColor: Colors.white,
                                onPressed: () {},
                              )));
                          return Text('there is something error');
                        }
                        
                      },
                    ),)
```

and login method:

```
``Future<void> logIn() async {
    print('inside login method');
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      try {
        await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: emailController.text.trim(),
          password: passwordController.text.trim(),
        );
        print('end try');
      } catch (e) {
        if (emailController.text.isNotEmpty &&
            passwordController.text.isNotEmpty) {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
              content: const Text('Invalid email/password'),
              backgroundColor: Colors.red.shade400,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(6, 0, 3, 0),
              behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
              action: SnackBarAction(
                label: 'Dismiss',
                disabledTextColor: Colors.white,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                onPressed: () {},
              )));
          print("after check");
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

`
each textFormField is have the correct controller
and because of this problem I can't run this method correctly

Comment: which line is causing the issue?

Comment: when I want to write in email/password box this is repreent